# Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )

Tags: java, file, error-handling, escaping

I am trying to read a file into my Java program using java.util.Scanner and I get the above message when I enter the code below (I am new to java) - can anyone help? (I looked at a similar message someone got with their own code, but it was too complex for me to use in my example!). I have Windows 7.

```
BufferedReader job = new BufferedReader
               (new FileReader("\My Documents\JOBS\newfile.txt"));
```

Answer (score 36):

You need to escape the "\" in the file path.

```
BufferedReader job = new BufferedReader 
               (new FileReader("\\My Documents\\JOBS\\newfile.txt"));
```

Answer (score 20):

`\` is an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), use `\\`

Comment: Hi Yi, thanks for super-quick reply - replace all \ with \\ or particular one - which one?

Comment: all of them. read the article. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Programming_and_data_formats

Answer (score 0):

If you're using eclipse, there's a setting that inserts escape chars automatically when pasting:

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing -> In String Literals -> Escape text when pasting into a string literal

Then, when something like `D:\Env\Images\image1.png` is in your clipboard and you paste it into eclipse, it'll automatically look like this: `D:\\Env\\Images\\image1.png`

Answer (score 0):

On trying to look out a solution to a similar issue I faced a while ago, I realised such an issue sometimes is operating system dependent. I'm using windows 11. Could you believe that, changing all the backward slashes to forwards had the issue/error fixed? Though I'm late to the discussion, it might help in the future.