# Java - filepath - Invalid escape sequence

Tags: java, filepath

I am uploading file to a destination by providing filepath.
It works fine when file path is like

```
String filePath = "D:\\location";
```

But while providing a server location like

```
String filePath = request.getRealPath("\\10.0.1.18\downloads\upload");
```

produce error of invalid escape sequence.

Whats wrong in the path ( i have full priveledges to the location) and if wrong how too impliment it correctly.

Thanks for help in advance////

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445196/invalid-escape-sequence-valid-ones-are-b-t-n-f-r

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a compile-time error, so it *can't* be to do with permissions etc.

The problem is that you're not escaping the backslashes. You need:

```
String filePath = request.getRealPath("\\\\10.0.1.18\\downloads\\upload");
```

Then the contents of the string will be just

```
\\10.0.1.18\downloads\upload
```

This is exactly the same as in the first line you showed, where this:

```
String filePath = "D:\\location";
```

... will actually create a string with contents of:

```
D:\location
```

See [section 3.10.6 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) for more details of escape sequences within character and string literals.

Answer (score 5):

use double slash `\\` ! It's a special escape pattern. Like \n or \r.